# What kind of languages can be recognized by a restricted one-tape deterministic Turing Machine?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-sensitive, linear-bounded-automata

During a lesson, our TA asked:

> What kind of languages can be recognized by a *deterministic* Turing
>   Machine such that we can use only a tape *portion* that contains the input?

**My thoughts:**
my Theory of Computation book says that there is a special TM called *linear bounded automaton* (LBA) that corresponds to a *non-deterministic* Turing Machine that has a limited tape. Such machine recognize Context Sensitive languages.

So if i simulate the LBA behavior starting from a *deterministc* TM, may I recognize "deterministic"-Context Sensitive Languages?

Answer (score 2):

It's [famously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_bounded_automaton#LBA_problems) unknown whether deterministic and non-deterministic LBA accept the same set of languages.